# SQL data set not being overwritten

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

In my visual studio 2013 code i am using a loop to produce multiple pieces of information, however the data set created by my SQL statement doesn't seem to be updating on every loop.

The issue occurs on the second loop, where the statement:

```
playerName = ds.tables("Standings").Rows(0).item(2) will only access the first value found

SQL = "SELECT * FROM Standings WHERE (TournamentID) = (" & TournamentId & ") AND PlayerID = (" & player1ID & ")"
        Console.WriteLine(SQL)

playerName = ds.Tables("Standings").Rows(0).Item(2).ToString
        Console.WriteLine(playerName)
        player1Name = playerName

        Console.WriteLine(player1Name)
```

### The Console logs produced when I execute the code:

```
Participants = 16

New Loop
0
SELECT * FROM Pairings WHERE TournamentId = ('2') AND RoundNumber = ('1')

New Information
475
18
SELECT * FROM Standings WHERE (TournamentID) = (2) AND PlayerID = (18)
Raspberry
Raspberry
UPDATE Pairings SET Player1Name='Raspberry' WHERE MatchID = 475

New Loop
2
SELECT * FROM Pairings WHERE TournamentId = ('2') AND RoundNumber = ('1')

New Information
477
31
SELECT * FROM Standings WHERE (TournamentID) = (2) AND PlayerID = (31)
Raspberry
Raspberry
UPDATE Pairings SET Player1Name='Raspberry' WHERE MatchID = 477

New Loop
4
SELECT * FROM Pairings WHERE TournamentId = ('2') AND RoundNumber = ('1')

New Information
479
34
SELECT * FROM Standings WHERE (TournamentID) = (2) AND PlayerID = (34)
Raspberry
Raspberry
UPDATE Pairings SET Player1Name='Raspberry' WHERE MatchID = 479

New Loop
6 
SELECT * FROM Pairings WHERE TournamentId = ('2') AND RoundNumber = ('1')

New Information
481
17
SELECT * FROM Standings WHERE (TournamentID) = (2) AND PlayerID = (17)
Raspberry
Raspberry
UPDATE Pairings SET Player1Name='Raspberry' WHERE MatchID = 481

New Loop
8
SELECT * FROM Pairings WHERE TournamentId = ('2') AND RoundNumber = ('1')

New Information 
483
33
SELECT * FROM Standings WHERE (TournamentID) = (2) AND PlayerID = (33)
Raspberry
Raspberry
UPDATE Pairings SET Player1Name='Raspberry' WHERE MatchID = 483

New Loop
10
SELECT * FROM Pairings WHERE TournamentId = ('2') AND RoundNumber = ('1')

New Information
485
28
SELECT * FROM Standings WHERE (TournamentID) = (2) AND PlayerID = (28)
Raspberry
Raspberry
UPDATE Pairings SET Player1Name='Raspberry' WHERE MatchID = 485

New Loop
12
SELECT * FROM Pairings WHERE TournamentId = ('2') AND RoundNumber = ('1')

New Information
487
29
SELECT * FROM Standings WHERE (TournamentID) = (2) AND PlayerID = (29)
Raspberry
Raspberry
UPDATE Pairings SET Player1Name='Raspberry' WHERE MatchID = 487

New Loop
14
SELECT * FROM Pairings WHERE TournamentId = ('2') AND RoundNumber = ('1')

New Information
489
24
SELECT * FROM Standings WHERE (TournamentID) = (2) AND PlayerID = (24)
Raspberry
Raspberry
UPDATE Pairings SET Player1Name='Raspberry' WHERE MatchID = 489
```

## The full code:

(in case of another error affecting it)

```
     For i = 0 To ((participants) - 1) Step 2
        con.Open()
        con2.Open()


        Console.WriteLine("")
        Console.WriteLine("New Loop")
        Console.WriteLine(i)

        SQL2 = "SELECT * FROM Pairings WHERE TournamentId = ('" & TournamentId & "') AND RoundNumber = ('" & roundNumberValue & "')"

        Console.WriteLine(SQL2)
        da2 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQL2, con2)
        da2.Fill(ds2, "Pairings")

        'searching for playerid

        matchId = ds2.Tables("Pairings").Rows(i).Item("MatchID")
        player1ID = Outputlist(i).ToString
        Console.WriteLine("")
        Console.WriteLine("New Information")
        Console.WriteLine(matchId)
        Console.WriteLine(player1ID)


        'dataset only contains row 0 with player1id and tournamentid
        SQL = "SELECT * FROM Standings WHERE (TournamentID) = (" & TournamentId & ") AND PlayerID = (" & player1ID & ")"
        Console.WriteLine(SQL)

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Standings")

        Dim dbCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        dbCommand.Connection = con
        dbCommand.CommandText = SQL
        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Dim playerName As String
        'can only pull 1 piece of data out ( there is only row 0)
        'not changing the value even though the search changes. ( can the dataset not be overwritten?, Or is not being overwritten? )
        playerName = ds.Tables("Standings").Rows(0).Item(2).ToString
        Console.WriteLine(playerName)
        player1Name = playerName
        Console.WriteLine(player1Name)
        If player1Name = "Bye" Then
            SQL2 = "update Pairings Set Player1Name'" & player1Name & "' WHERE MatchID = " & matchId & ""
        Else
            'SQL = "UPDATE Standings SET Points='" & playerNewScore(1) & "' WHERE PlayerID= '" & lblPlayer1.Text & "'"
            SQL2 = "UPDATE Pairings SET Player1Name='" & player1Name & "' WHERE MatchID = " & matchId & ""
            Console.WriteLine(SQL2)
        End If

        Dim dbCommand2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        dbCommand2.Connection = con2
        dbCommand2.CommandText = SQL2
        dbCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        con2.Close()
    Next
```

Comment: Please Google SQL Injection. Also, you'll thank yourself in the future if you avoid using `SELECT *`

Comment: I believe that the `Fill` method adds a new table to your dataset each time. So, the one from the very first call is still there. Subsequent calls will add new tables, I believe named `Standings2`, `Standings3`, etc. There's probably a better "standard" way of doing this.